# How to use Digimarc-protection on my files in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copy-protection

How many of you use or have used [Digimarc](https://www.digimarc.com/)? (It's kind of embedded, human–imperceptible watermark for your creation such as wallpaper, images and artwork.)

If anyone has used it (Digimarc watermark), can you please suggest how to use Digimarc with Photoshop? Is it okay to consider copyright for my own creations? Unfortunately, though, there seems to be only paid subscriptions available.

Comment: What is your question exactly? I don't understand

Comment: I'm almost certain you are interested in "copy protection" and not issues of legal "copyright." I edited your question but, if my assumption is incorrect, please feel free to roll back the edit. I'm still not entirely certain of what you are actually asking for, though.

Comment: it's clearer now, but you should add what kind of work you do. If you make expensive stock images, buying Digimarc might be a justified expense. If you are a hobby artist, maybe not. It all depends on the use case.

Answer (score 4):

Copyright is a legal concept and, therefore, you protect it via our legal system. That includes registering your work and suing folks (and it'll vary from country to country).

If you're asking about physical copy protection, there's a variety of technologies out there and none of them really will stop physical copying of your work if people really want to copy it.

Comment: I think he is referring to [Digimarc](https://www.digimarc.com/)'s products speficially but it is not really clear what he means

Comment: Well, the answer still stands. Physical copyright protection only benefits the companies like Digimarc. They do nothing to prevent people from copying your media if they want to. They also do nothing to protect you legally.

Answer (score 4):

I use the "file info..." option to fill out copyright information. This has the nice effect that a little © appears next to the filename (in the tabs in photoshop)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the text-tool and the shape tool for making a watermark at the top layer. Then choose transparancy for the watermark for that layer.
[image]

The whole point is that no one will stop people from copying stuff. But you can make it very hard for them, like I do. I actually picked a wallpaper from a game for my art, hehe pretty funny.

Comment: Why did someone downvote me? I was trying to help...

Comment: Removed downvote as it went without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to filter, scroll to Digimarc, choose embed Watermark.

Below is probably the information you already read, but just in case here it is again:

> You can add copyright information to Photoshop images and notify users that an image is copyright-protected via a digital watermark that uses Digimarc ImageBridge technology. The watermark—a digital code added as noise to the image—is virtually imperceptible to the human eye. The Digimarc watermark is durable in both digital and printed forms, surviving typical image edits and file format conversions.
>
> Embedding a digital watermark in an image lets viewers obtain information about the creator of the image. This feature is particularly valuable to image creators who license their work to others. Copying an image with an embedded watermark also copies the watermark and any information associated with it.
>
> For more detailed information on embedding Digimarc digital watermarks, refer to the Digimarc website at www.digimarc.com.

Comment: +1 i know how to  use this but when we move to further process it ask you for some registration (of course money) :|